# Show numbers as times in xAxis of linechart in dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I have a csv file with column (arr_time_) that represents which 15 minute time period this specific transaction has happened.

[image]

The values in this column range from `0 to 28`, each representing a 15 minute period starting at 6 am. So `0` means `6 am`, 1 means `6:15 am`, etc. This is how my line chart looks like now:
[image]

My dc.js code for this line chart is this:

```
timeChart
    .width(800)
    .height(230)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 30})
    .dimension(arrivalTimeDim)
    .group(arrivalPer15min, "Observed")
    // .ordinalColors(["orange"])
    // .stack(histArrivalPer15min, "historical")
    .transitionDuration(500)
    .renderArea(true)
    // .elasticX(true)
    .elasticY(true)
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([minDate, maxDate+.5]))//minDate=0, maxDate=28
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    // .legend(dc.legend().x(60).y(10).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
    .xAxisLabel("Time")
    .yAxis().ticks(4);
    // .xAxis().ticks(5);
```

I want to change the xAXis in this chart so that it shows `6, 6:15, ...`. I've tried using `.range` and `xUnits`but, probably because I did it wrong, it didn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps you could make use of the d3.time.scale for your x axis?

Comment: I've done this .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate+.5]))
  .xUnits(d3.time.hour)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you will need to create the Date in the dataset:

```
  var today = new Date(2015, 12, 25);//sample date for which the data is a part i am considering it to to be 25 Dec 2015 
  var hrs = 6;//since you want to start from 6 in the morning
  experiments.forEach(function(x) {
    x.Speed = +x.Speed;
    //making the Date data
    x.Date = new Date(today.getTime()+ hrs*60*60*1000)
    hrs +=0.25;//after 15 minutes data
  });

//this will calculate the max min for the date
var extent = d3.extent(experiments, function(d){return d.Date});
```

Finally set the axis like below:

```
  chart
    .width(768)
    .height(480)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain(extent))
    .xUnits(d3.time.minute)
```

Working code sample [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6rnouYDfsdZHGwpahQOC?p=preview).

Comment: just one last thing, do you know how to NOT show the "AM" or "PM" parts? it creates too much clutter and it's unreadable

Comment: Do this   `chart.xAxis().tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M"));` updated teh fiddle for more formatting information read this http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/raw/ca0adb7e426c12c06a95/